# How can I version beta releases with npm semantic-release?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions, semantic-release

Before anything, let me explain my current setup:

- I have 2 branches on my github repo: "main" and "develop"
- main is the production one
- develop is the dev&test environment
- develop will always be ahead of main in terms of versioning. While in main I'll have v0.7.0, on develop I will have v0.7.1

Expected behaviour:

- after pushing from develop to main, main should update to develop version (v0.7.1)
- I alreay created 2 tags and releases (v0.7.0-beta for main branch, v0.7.0-betaDev for develop branch)

Currently when using npm semantic release on github actions (where my CICD is), it always says that there is no release version and it creates a v1.0.0 version.

Here is my package.json config for npm semantic release:

```
  "release": {
    "branches": [{"name": "main"},{"name": "develop", "prerelease": true}],
    "npmPublish": false,
    "plugins": [
      "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
      "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
      "@semantic-release/npm",
      ["@semantic-release/github", {
        "successComment": false,
        "failComment": false,
        "releasedLabels": false
      }],
      [
        "@semantic-release/git",
        {
          "assets": [],
          "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As I stated, what I need is to create tags and releases with version under 1.0.0 and specially pushin them from dev to main (dev could have v0.7.25 and main being v0.7.0, when I push from dev to main, main should have the tag and release v0.7.25 so it is aligned with dev)